# Postgresql string_agg and crash issue

Tags: postgresql

We have a view which does **string_agg** on a table with 54 million records where string_agg need to process 2 strings per group. View definition using query like following is resulting in postgresql server process to die due to out of memory.

`SELECT id, string_agg(msg, “,”) FROM msgs GROUP BY id`

When the view query is modified as below, it is working fine.

```
SELECT id, string_agg(msg, ',') as msgs
FROM ( SELECT id, msg, row_number() over (partition by id) as row_num 
       FROM msgs) as limited_alerts
WHERE row_num < 5
GROUP BY id
```

What is the reason? Is it because postgres is able to use temporary files in 2nd case ? Are there any links/articles which explains the details ?

## Table msgs

- id      bigint PRIMARY KEY
- service text
- msg     text

> Total number of rows: 54 million
>
> Max num of msgs per id: 2

Looks like the one which crashes is using HashAggregate and other one GroupAggregate

```
explain select count(*) from (SELECT msgs.id, string_agg(msgs.alerts, ','::text) AS alerts FROM msgs GROUP BY msgs.id) as a;
                                              QUERY PLAN                                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=3032602.58..3032602.59 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3032597.58..3032600.08 rows=200 width=108)
         Group Key: msgs.id
         ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2587883.05 rows=88942906 width=108)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=548)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_01_24  (cost=0.00..506305.40 rows=17394640 width=107)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_01_31  (cost=0.00..509979.80 rows=17512480 width=107)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_02_07  (cost=0.00..491910.32 rows=16883332 width=108)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_02_14  (cost=0.00..496443.84 rows=17071384 width=108)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_02_21  (cost=0.00..552162.84 rows=19026084 width=108)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_02_28  (cost=0.00..31038.05 rows=1054705 width=111)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_03_06  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=70 width=548)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_03_13  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=70 width=548)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_03_20  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=70 width=548)
               ->  Seq Scan on msgs_2016_03_27  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=70 width=548)
```

Comment: Could you post the explain analyze results here please?

Comment: I have added EXPLAIN for the query which crashed. Looks like the one which crashes is using HashAggregate and other one GroupAggregate.

Comment: Can you add the **exact** Postgres version (`select version()`)  you are using? What is the value of `work_mem`?

Comment: Postgres 9.4 (work_mem: 32 MB). Looks like we got some clue. This query was done after restoring a big DB. HashAggregate seems to be selected as planner calculated 200 distinct rows. After a manual VACUUM ANALYZE it took a different plan using GroupAggregate and crash is fixed. I am not sure why periodic stats collector failed to update even after hours.